# sql oracle case when date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case

This is what I got so far:

```
select
to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') Time
from 
dual;
```

Which gives me:

```
TIME

2015
```

Its working until this point.

I would like to add

- if the month is `>= 7` I get as output `01.07.current year`
- if the month is `<= 7` I get as output `01.07.(current year - 1 year)`

Any ideas how to handle this? I thought about CASE WHEN but I dont get know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple **CASE** expression would do the job.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    '01.07.' ||
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') < '07'
  5      THEN 
  6        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
  7      ELSE
  8        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-12), 'YYYY')
  9    END case_date
  10 FROM dual;

CASE_DATE
----------
01.07.2015

SQL>
```

To keep it even more precise, you could keep the common value outside the CASE expression:

```
SQL> SELECT '01.07.'
  2    ||
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') < '07'
  5      THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
  6      ELSE TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-12), 'YYYY')
  7    END case_date
  8  FROM dual;

CASE_DATE
----------
01.07.2015

SQL>
```

Comment: @Okdel Thanks for suggesting an edit. Since there was content being lost from the explanation part, I have to improve it myself. So, I accepted your edit and improved it.

Answer (score 1):

Using extract more readable

```
SELECT
 to_date((CASE
             WHEN extract(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) >= 7 THEN
              0
             ELSE
              -1
         END) + extract(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) || '07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') END
  FROM dual
```